# Drupal 7. When editing the content type appears this error

Tags: drupal

Drupal 7. When editing the content type appears this error.

**Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.**

**Original**

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away:
SELECT s.lid, t.translation, s.version FROM {locales_source} s LEFT JOIN {locales_target} t ON s.lid = t.lid AND t.language = :language WHERE s.source = :source AND s.context = :context AND s.textgroup = &#039;default&#039;; Array ( [:language] =&gt; ru [:source] =&gt; Configure how content input by users is filtered, including allowed HTML tags. Also allows enabling of module-provided filters. [:context] =&gt; ) in locale() (line 720 of S:\home\go\www\modules\locale\locale.module).
```

**Additional**

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: 
SELECT s.lid, t.translation, s.version FROM {locales_source} s LEFT JOIN {locales_target} t ON s.lid = t.lid AND t.language = :language WHERE s.source = :source AND s.context = :context AND s.textgroup = &#039;default&#039;; Array ( [:language] =&gt; ru [:source] =&gt; A field which is not visible to the user, but is recorded with the submission. [:context] =&gt; ) in locale() (line 720 of S:\home\go\www\modules\locale\locale.module).
```

**Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.**

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 
2006 MySQL server has gone away in _drupal_session_write() (line 209 of S:\home\go\www\includes\session.inc).
```

Comment: MySQL server "goes away" when your connection times out or if your db server is experiencing memory issues. Please provide details about your apache/mysql and your site's configuration to better understand what is going on. Further elaboration about what you where actually doing while editing the content type could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your max_allowed_packet in my.cnf (or if on MAMP, my-medium.cnf or whichever size you're using.).

Answer (score 0):

I use wamp on windows 10. Encountered the same problem.
Changed `max_allowed_packet` to 20M in `C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\my.ini` , finish.